# Problem with recursive factorial in x86_64 Assembly

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86-64, att

I'm new to this assembly language and I tried to do the following code on my own. The problem is that my code cannot calculate the factorial of a number correctly and it always shows 1 as an output in the terminal. I'd like to know the reason why it is not working.

```
.text

mystring1: .asciz "Assignment 4: recursion\nType any number to calculate the factorial of that number:\n"  # string for printing message
formatstr: .asciz "%ld"                   # format string for printing number
mystring2: .asciz "\n"                    # string for printing a new line

.global main  # make the main label visible  

main:

    pushq %rbp            # store the caller's base pointer
    movq %rsp, %rbp       # initialise the base pointer
    movq $0, %rax         # no vector registers in use for printf
    movq $mystring1, %rdi # load address of a string
    call printf           # call the printf subroutine
    call inout            # call the inout subroutine
    movq $0, %rax         # no vector registers in use for printf
    movq $mystring2, %rdi # load address of a string
    call printf
    jmp end

inout:

    pushq %rbp                  # push the base pointer
    movq %rsp, %rbp             # copy the stack pointer to rbp
    subq $16, %rsp              # reserve stack space for variable
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi         # load address of stack variable in rsi
    movq $formatstr, %rdi       # load first argument of scanf
    movq $0, %rax               # no vector registers in use for scanf
    call scanf                  # call scanf routine
    movq -8(%rbp), %rsi         # move the address of the variable to rsi
    call factorial
    movq $0, %rax               # no vector registers in use for printf
    movq $formatstr, %rdi       # move the address formatstring to rdi
    call printf                 # print the result
    movq %rbp, %rsp             # copy rbp to rsp
    popq %rbp                   # pop rbp from the stack
    ret                         # return from the subroutine

factorial:

    cmpq $1, %rsi
    jle factend
    pushq %rbx
    movq %rsi, %rbx
    subq $1, %rsi
    call factorial
    mulq %rbx
    popq %rbx
    ret

factend:

    movq $1, %rax
    ret

end:
    mov $0, %rdi # load program exit code
    call exit    # exit the program
```

The pseudocode of my code:

```
long rfact(long n)
{
     long result;
     if (n < = 1)
     {
        result = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        result = n * rfact(n - 1);
        return result;
     }
}
```

Comment: You're not using the high-half RDX result of `mulq`.  Use the more efficient 2-operand `imul %rbx, %rax`.  BTW, the x86-64 System V calling convention passes the first integer/pointer arg in RDI.  You're already doing that for args to printf and scanf so it's odd that you chose RSI for your own function.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I still have a lot to learn and I just randomly used RSI but thank you nonetheless for the information

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm teaching you :P

Comment: Haha I appreciate much. Also please point out if anything else needs to be mentioned :)

Comment: Well since you asked, oh so many things if you care about efficiency.  xor-zeroing, RIP-relative LEA, (google those or search on SO), and `mov $1, %eax` zero-extends to RAX implicitly; no need to waste code-size on 64-bit operand size.  (Same for addresses; if you're optimizing for a position-dependent Linux executable, use `mov $formatstr, %edi`, not `%rdi`, when you don't need a RIP-relative LEA to put a static address in a register.  `movq $sign_extended_32bit_immediate, %rdi` takes more space for no benefit, and GAS doesn't do this optimization for you even for numeric constants.)

Comment: But as far as correctness and good style, you're doing pretty well here.  e.g. using stack space in the caller for scanf scratch space.  Save/restore of RBX across `factorial` and using it to save your local variable is what compilers would do.  Oh, put your string literals in `.section .rodata`, code in `.text`.  If you're curious, put your C into https://godbolt.org/ and see how it compiles with `-O1`, or with `-O2`.  ... now I'm curious: https://godbolt.org/z/YkxAYS shows that GCC -O1 makes something pretty close to what you did.  clang -O1 still optimizes the simple recursion into a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the result of your factorial in `rax`, but your caller is assuming that it is in `rsi`.  The caller should move the result from `rax` to where it is needed (`rsi` in this case) right after the call to `factorial` returns.